# How to change the title bar color in windows terminal(installed from ms store)

Tags: windows-10, terminal, windows-terminal, microsoft-store

I am trying to change the color of the title in windows terminal. Is there any way to change title bar color. \

**default one**
[image]

**Desired one**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the setting file, `settings.json`, type: `"theme": "dark",` to use the dark theme.

[image]

The [themes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/terminal/customize-settings/global-settings#darklight-theme) are:

> **Dark/Light theme**
>
> This sets the theme of the application. "system" will use the same theme as Windows.
>
> **Property name:** theme
>
> **Necessity:** Optional
>
> **Accepts:** "system", "dark", "light"
>
> **Default value:** "system"

Comment: Thank You it works fine

Comment: This is a great option to combine with the [blue matrix scheme](https://dev.to/anupa/beautify-your-windows-terminal-1la8)